# backbone-froms multiple views submit a form

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-forms

I have a master view `App.MainView` (table view), a `App.TaskView` (row view) and using backbone forms to add and edit the records. Here is my code:

```
App.MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: $("#home-template").html(),
            initialize: function() {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
               this.listenTo(tasks, 'add change', this.addOne);
               this.subViews = [];


            },
addOne: function(model) {


                var view = new App.TaskView({model: model});
                this.$('tbody').append(view.render().el);
            },
render: function() {

                var template = _.template(this.template);
                this.$el.append(template);
                //this.$el.find("#filter").append(this.createSelect());
                var self = this;


                this.collection.fetch({
                    wait: true,
                    success: function(model, response) {


                        var TasksLen = model.length;

                        for (var i = 0; i < TasksLen; i++) {

                            var taskView = new App.TaskView({
                                model: model.models[i]
                            });


                            //self.subViews.push(taskView);

                            $('#record-list-table', this.el).append(taskView.render().el);

                        }
                    }

                });
  },

Now my TaskView:

 App.TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'tr',
            template: _.template($('#record-template').html()),
initialize: function() {
                var self = this;

            },
events: {

                "click .edit": "editrecord",



            },
render: function() {

                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))

                return this;



            },
 editrecord: function() {

                form.setValue(this.model.toJSON());
}

and my Form and submit button 

var form = new Backbone.Form({
            model: task
        });

        window.form = form;
       $('#form').html(form.render().el);

        $('#submit-btn').click(function() {

            var data = form.getValue();
            form.commit();
             task.save(data, {wait: true,
                    success: function(task, response) {
                         tasks.add(task);

                    }


                }); 
Templates:
<script type="text/template" id="home-template">
 <table id="recordtable">
<input type='reset' id="reset-btn" onclick="reset()" class="add-new" value='' name='reset' /></table></script>


<script type="text/template" id="record-template">

    <td id="edit-name" class="edit"> <%- name %></td>
    <td class="edit date" class="edit"> <%- due_date %></td>

</script>
```

I have two issues:

1. On model change,it adds another model (However it does the put request and updates in database but on front end backbone adds a new row in the table instead of updating the previous row). But after page refresh it shows correct data. Looks like some issue with change event.
2. I want to create direct route to a task i.e task/id and want to highlight that task in the table and edit it in the form. Right Now I am able to edit any model on click  in the form but I want to have direct route too.

Answer (score 0):

I think now I found the problem of your code. You are doing

```
 tasks.add(task);
```

in success method of model save. But I think you need to re render the task.
 1. You can bind a change event in taskview so that it will render task with updated value.
 2. You can add a function in your taskview like this

```
refresh: function(){
     this.render();
}
```

and you can call this function after model.save success found.

Comment: I have tried doing this but looks like its going to addOne function instead of render on change.

Comment: I think it's happenning because of this.
this.listenTo(tasks, 'add change', this.addOne);

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong so i have added after save on suceess success: function(task, response) {
                     var taskView = new App.TaskView();
                     taskView.refresh();

                    } and taskview have the refresh function refresh: function(){
     this.render();
},  i am getting error Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined (this.model is undefined). How can i pass model.

Comment: You need to pass model like this.
var taskView = new App.TaskView({model:yourModel});

Comment: Yes i am passing my model , but it renders new model on update looks like its not closing the previous view